# MultipartResolver is not working

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, spring-roo, multipart

I using developing a RESTFul web service using Maven and Spring Roo.

In my configuration xml file I defined a `multipartResolver` bean because I am uploading files of 300KB:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="400000" />
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="400000" />
</bean>
```

The files are uploaded successfully and pushed into a stack. These file are `CommonsMultipartFile` or `MultipartFile` objects (I have the same phenomenon for both type of objects). Once I pop a file, I can call `getSize()` method and I can verify that the size of the file is correct. But once I call `getInputStream()` I get the following error: `File has been moved - cannot be read again.`

Did I do something wrong in my `multipartResolver` declaration? Is there any other reason to have this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to getInputStream() is being recognized as a request to get the input stream of the file on the client-side. And as the file has been already uploaded it says "file has been moved - cannot read again"

also what are you trying to do by calling getInputStream()? If you want to read the uploaded file, create a new FileInputStream with the path of the uploaded location and access the file contents.

Comment: Thank you Vivek for the clarification! Yes I want to read the file, the file is in a stack and It is not saved in a specific path yet... how can I apply your proposition in my case? Thank you and excuse my basic questions.

Comment: can you add some more code snippet of your application,, especially the file upload part please,,

Comment: It is resolved Vivek, thank you. I did not know that once the file is uploaded it will be deleted from the server. Now, once I receive the file in the server I save it and then I can open it and read it.