# File has been moved - cannot be read again

Tags: java, jsp, session, spring-mvc

I stored multipartfile to session and I retrieved it to display in table. when I click on this file, I got the error as follow,

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/cims] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: File has been moved - cannot be read again] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: File has been moved - cannot be read again
```

This is my coding in controller. I saw someone used getBinaryStream() but in my coding I can't call this one. Please give me some advice .Thanks.

```
@RequestMapping("/claim/transportation/download/{docId}")
    public String download(@PathVariable("docId") Integer docId, @ModelAttribute("dataHolderPrmClaimTransportationSession") DataHolderPrmClaimTransportationSession dataHolderPrmClaimTransportationSession,HttpServletResponse response){
        System.out.print(docId); System.out.println("DocID");
        try{
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\""+dataHolderPrmClaimTransportationSession.getUiPrmClaimTransportation().getTransportationRecordList().get(docId).getUploadFile().getOriginalFilename()+"\"");
            System.out.println("DocIDHeader");
            System.out.println(dataHolderPrmClaimTransportationSession.getUiPrmClaimTransportation().getTransportationRecordList().get(docId).getUploadFile().getOriginalFilename());
            OutputStream out=response.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println(out);
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            IOUtils.copy(dataHolderPrmClaimTransportationSession.getUiPrmClaimTransportation().getTransportationRecordList().get(docId).getUploadFile().getInputStream(),out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

---

This is from JSP.

```
<td id="selfTableAttachedFile"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/hra/prm/claim/transportation/download/${status.index}" target="_blank">${record.uploadFile.originalFilename }</a></td>
```

Comment: see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747430/problem-with-spring-fileupload)

Comment: thanks. I saw that one. I added maxupload but sill has the error .